# Seleccionar span que tenga un atributo específico, sin jquery, solo javascript

Tags: javascript

Necesito poner la palabra "hola" en el span que contenga el atributo "data-cualquiercosa", es decir, para este span:

```
<span data-cualquiercosa="asdasda"></span>
```

Necesito hacer esto:

```
$("span[data-cualquiercosa]").html("hola");
```

Nótese que esto de arriba es con JQuery, pero necesito saber cómo hacer lo mismo con javascript puro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En JavaScript puro existen dos funciones que te pueden servir:

- [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector): selecciona y devuelve un único elemento que cumpla el selector especificado. Si hay varios, sólo devuelve el primer elemento que cumpla el selector.
- [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll): selecciona todos los elementos que cumplen el selector especificado. Devuelve una lista con todos esos elementos.

En tu caso, como es un solo elemento, te valdrá `querySelector`.

Y para cambiar el texto de dentro puedes usar:

- [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML): permite poner texto o HTML dentro de la etiqueta; o
- [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent): sólo escribe texto.

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando:

```js
document.querySelector("span[data-cualquiercosa]").textContent = "hola";
```

```html
<span data-cualquiercosa="asdasda"></span>
```

Comment: muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Basta usar document.querySelector (cuando el elemento se asume único), document.querySelectorAll (cuando se asumen varios elementos)

```js
var span = document.querySelector('span[data-cualquiercosa="asdasda"]')

span.style.display = 'block'
span.style.height = '30px'
span.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'
span.style.color = 'white'

span.appendChild(
  document.createTextNode('Modificado desde DOM')
)
```

```html
<span data-cualquiercosa="asdasda"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres cambiar todos los elementos que tengan ese atributo, puedes usar [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) a partir de IE8+:

```js
// IE 8+
var elementos = document.querySelectorAll('[data-cualquiercosa="asdasda"]');
console.log(elementos[0]);
[].forEach.call(elementos, function(elemento) {
  elemento.innerHTML = 'Otro texto';
});
```

```html
<span data-cualquiercosa="asdasda"></span>
<br />
<span data-cualquiercosa="asdasda">1</span>
```

---

No obstante, recomiendo que leas este artículo:  [Don’t use data attributes to find HTML elements with JS](https://intuio.at/blog/dont-use-data-attributes-to-find-html-elements-with-js/)